# Google Sheet Formula to sum based on conditions

Tags: google-sheets-query

The following formula is designed to sum column C when column B contains a specific string:

=sum(query(A:C, " select C where B contains '2018-09-10' "))

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjiJS.png

It looks straightforward but it doesn't work in the Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qpQiwxHOUzoMTqHnn-m-nsnvl63YJkVIGgqpXzOZgzU/edit?usp=sharing

Am I missing something? Others have posted similar threads but this problem looks specific to this particular use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

months late but saw this searching for a similar problem, the problem comes from that what sheets stores with a date is different than what you see if you change it to:

`=sum(query(A:C, " select C where B = date '2018-09-10' "))`

it should work, alternatively, you can just select the column and choose Format -> Number -> Plain Text and your formula will work but then you won't be able to treat it as a date elsewhere in the sheet

Answer (score 0):

By Cell Reference:

```
=sum(query(A:C, " select C where B = date '"&TEXT(B3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1))
```